Do the addresses in ‘Dead Boy Detectives’ hold any special meaning?
The Netflix series Dead Boy Detectives takes place in Port Townsend, Washington State. As with most shows, the precise addresses of various locations in the show are not really mentioned or focused on, but two addresses are clearly shown:

The anonymous letters sent to Jenny show that the address of the Tongue & Tail Butcher Shop is 485 16th Street, Port Townsend, WA 98368
The letters from Niko’s mother in Japan (shown in ep. 4, around the 48:25 mark) corroborates that address and adduces that Niko’s mother’s address is 5-chōme-14 North Ōyoda, North Ward, Ōsaka, 531-0076

Unusually for a supernatural kind of series, both of these are real, actual addresses, rather than being made up à la all the phone numbers in movies that start with 555. Or at least, they’re almost real addresses. Looking at the Google Maps satellite view, there doesn’t seem to actually be a house at number 485 on 16th Street in Port Townsend (the closest number is 550), and 5-chōme-14 appears to technically be located in the Central Ōyoda (Ōyodanaka) neighbourhood, rather than North Ōyoda (Ōyodakita) – although the border between the two is right on the very street that 5-chōme-14 runs along.
The Port Townsend address on Google Maps is very different from the one in the show: in the show, it’s a small-town street with a takeaway, a butcher and some other shops, whereas in the real world, it seems to be an affluent semi-rural residential area with detached houses in forest surroundings, so at least it doesn’t seem like the show is trying to accurately portray a real-life place.
I’m aware the series is based on comics by Neil Gaiman, but I’ve never read the comics and don’t know that much about Gaiman, beyond the fact that he’s English and not obviously tied with either Washington or Osaka (to my knowledge).
Were these addresses taken over from the comics or chosen for the Netflix series? And is there any particular known significance to why these particular addresses were chosen?

DBD was filmed in Vancouver in a town that looks nothing like Port Townsend. They didn't even bother sending a crew to get some external framing shots of the real town. I wouldn't read too much into the addresses.

@Shawn Yeah, I did see an article about the locations (though it did say that they had at least chosen a place that matched it better than most of the Canadian coastline would have). But there was really no reason to include such specific addresses to begin with – they could easily have just not shown the envelopes at all. The fact that they’re so explicitly shown, even filling up most of the screen, implies that they had some sort of function.
